# Issue with ui-multiselect display values after jquery migration from 1.9.1 to 3.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have changed jQuery and jQueryUI version from 1.9.1 to 3.7.1 and 1.9.2 to 1.13.1 respectively and using AngularJS version 1.2.5.

The ui-multiselect dropdown values are not displaying over the UI but when I am hovering over the text field of the dropdown, the value can be seen and also when I checked in debugger tool, the value is present inside the label.

I have changed the ui-multiselect CSS and JS file of 0.3.1 version but it still has the same issue.

Also, jQuery theme js file was upgraded to 1.13.1.
Attaching the snapshot of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cJcu.png)

Comment: Regarding the problem, it sounds like a z-index issue in your CSS. Use the DOM inspector to double check this and adjust as necessary. However, as an aside from the issue, if you're using Angular then you almost certainly shouldn't be using jQuery, and you absolutely definitely shouldn't be using jQueryUI.

Comment: I have checked the css but found no z-index property that is used and before jquery upgradation it was working fine.

Comment: I have added z-index property and tried, but no luck still same issue.